# How to fix this python errors of code, and i am using jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a new python code, this code is composed of a class Strategies and and a function called play game.
This is a native python code.

```
%matplotlib inline
from random import randint
from enum import Enum
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Strategie(Enum):
    changer = 1
    garder = 0

def play_game(stratergie):
    portes = [0,1,2]
    bonnes_portes = random.randint(0,2)
    premier_choix = randint(0,2)
    portes.remove(premier_choix)

    if premier_choix == bonnes_portes :
        portes.remove(portes.randint(0,1))
    else:
        portes = [bonnes_portes]

    deuxieme_choix = 0

    if (strategie == Strategie.garder):
        deuxieme_choix = premier_choix 
    else: 
        deuxieme_choix = portes[0]

    return deuxieme_choix == bonnes_portes

play_game(Strategie.changer)
```

when I compile this program, The compiler show me this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a9fed9101c49> in <module>()
----> 1 play_game(Strategie.changer)

NameError: name 'Strategie' is not defined
```

Comment: `class Stratergie(Enum):` against `Strategie` - You have a  typo in your code.

Comment: I'm getting different set of errors when I run this code. Is the code and error shared here updated properly?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

Now I my code work and the error is in the call of Randint function, i must delete random from random.randint, and the is the last version of my code.

```
%matplotlib inline
from random import randint, seed
from enum import Enum
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Strategie(Enum):
    changer = 1
    garder = 0

def play_game(strategie):
    portes = [0,1,2]
    bonnes_portes = randint(0,2)
    premier_choix = randint(0,2)
    portes.remove(premier_choix)

    if premier_choix == bonnes_portes :
        portes.remove(portes.randint(0,1))
    else:
        portes = [bonnes_portes]

    deuxieme_choix = 0

    if (strategie == Strategie.garder):
        deuxieme_choix = premier_choix 
    else: 
        deuxieme_choix = portes[0]

    return deuxieme_choix == bonnes_portes 

play_game(Strategie.changer)
```